# where can I get a copy of lilo mbr image now?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr

Package `lilo` used to ship its own version of MBR (which is superior than MS' BTW), but not any more now:

```sh
$ dpkg -L lilo | grep -i mbr || echo not found
not found
```

So where can I get a copy of such lilo mbr image now?

PS. I remember `syslinux` used to provide a mbr image file from one of its packages as well, and have found the following package after I first asked the question:

```
$ apt-cache show mbr
Package: mbr
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.1.11-5.1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Santiago Garcia Mantinan <manty@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 47
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
Filename: pool/universe/m/mbr/mbr_1.1.11-5.1_amd64.deb
Size: 19644
Description-en: Master Boot Record for IBM-PC compatible computers.
 The MBR is used in booting operating systems from the hard disk. It
 runs first, then transfers control to the operating system's loader
 which transfers control to the kernel.
```

But the reason I am specifically looking for lilo mbr is that, it has the advantage of being able to boot directly from extended partition, while the others can't.

Comment: My 18.04 still shows lilo. I do not think mbr is a separate package, but part of lilo. Ubuntu installer & Boot-Repair use syslinux as Windows type boot loader. But also new hardware since Windows 8 released in 2012 is now UEFI.